# Adding additional geometry column in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid, mercator

I'm importing many sets of geodata into PostGIS, and they have different `SRID`'s. (Some have `EPSG:3857`, some `EPSG:4326`, some something else).

I'd like to create an additional `geometry column`, eg. `the_geom_mercator` with `SRID` `EPSG:3857`, and also keep the original `geom` column in whatever `SRID` it came in.

How can I do this with a PostGIS function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To add a column to an existing table, use the [ALTER TABLE DDL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD COLUMN the_geom_mercator
    geometry(Geometry,3857);
```

which can be populated from another column (the_geom) using:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
  the_geom_mercator = ST_Transform(the_geom, 3857)
FROM spatial_ref_sys
WHERE ST_SRID(the_geom) = srid;
```

(the third line `FROM spatial_ref_sys ...` isn't necessary, but it guards transform attempts with unknown or invalid projections, which raise errors).

And if this table is to be maintained (added/updated), you can use a trigger function to update the_geom_mercator, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_table_tg_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND NEW.the_geom ISNULL THEN
    RETURN NEW; -- no new geometry
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    IF NEW.the_geom IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD.the_geom THEN
      RETURN NEW; -- same old geometry
    END IF;
  END IF;
  -- Attempt to transform a geometry
  BEGIN
    NEW.the_geom_mercator := ST_Transform(NEW.the_geom, 3857);
  EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE 'XX000' THEN
    RAISE WARNING 'the_geom_mercator not updated: %', SQLERRM;
  END;
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_table_tg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_table_tg_fn();
```

Note that ST_Transform should trap errors and show a warning, e.g.:

```
postgis=# INSERT INTO my_table(the_geom)
postgis-# VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0,1), 123))
postgis-# RETURNING the_geom, the_geom_mercator;
WARNING:  the_geom_mercator not updated: GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (123) in spatial_ref_sys
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+---------------------------------------------------
the_geom          | 01010000207B0000000000000000000000000000000000F03F
the_geom_mercator |

INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. It's real neat to use triggers, I will start doing so. Could I add that trigger to the database instead, so that i dont have to add this trigger for every new table?

Comment: I'm adding data to postgis with `shp2psql` and table is created when piped through `psql`. So I can't really add a trigger before table exists?

Comment: If you are using shp2pgsql, use an update statement, see above. A trigger is useful if you need to maintain a table, but not for loading.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an unconstrained SRID geometry column to hold the native form and then transform to existing.  Here is a contrived example assuming you have polygons that you are copying from a staging table (if you have mixed, you can set type to geometry e.g geometry(Geometry,3857):

```
CREATE TABLE poi(gid serial primary key, 
   geom_native geometry(POLYGON),  
   geom_mercator geometry(POLYGON,3857) );

INSERT INTO TABLE poi(geom_native, geom_mercator)
SELECT geom, ST_Transform(geom, 3857)
   FROM staging.imported_poly;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to do this on already existing tables (ie. without using staging tables)? Let's say I already have a table, with a `geom` column, and I simply want to add another `the_geom_webmercator` column. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First create a normal non-spatial table, which you already have.
Second add a spatial column to the table using the OpenGIS "AddGeometryColumn" function.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE terrain_points ( 
ogc_fid serial NOT NULL, 
elevation double precision,
);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('terrain_points', 'wkb_geometry', 3725, 'POINT', 3 );
```