# Does QGIS require a specific name for the geometry field in a PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I seemed to have noticed that QGIS cannot detect the spatial type or SRID of a PostGIS table if the geometry column is set to anything other than "geom". You can manually tell QGIS what these fields should be but then upon opening a saved project the tables in particular seem slow to load.

Is it recommended that "geom" is used for the geometry column to speed up the table reads or could this be something un-related.

[image]

Comment: QGIS is utilizing a special table "geometry_columns". You can read more about that from PostGIS documentation. If exact geometry type is stored into geometry_columns QGIS can pick it directly.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 so it would appear that the type and srid fields in the "geometry_columns" table are not set. Do these need to be defined when creating the views?

Comment: You need to define a column as geometry column in PostGIS. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154906/adding-additional-geometry-column-in-postgis for example. So far I never had issues defining multiple geometry columns of diverse names, not even when CRS and Geometrytypes are mixed.